# Extjs 4 portlet on load collapsed not working properly

Tags: extjs4

I am using ExtJS portal code in my application

I want to make portlet in collapsed state at the time of loading the page. So I have done something like

```
items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-1',
                            title: 'Grid Portlet Texsds',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            height:200,
                            **collapsed:true,**
                            autoScroll :true,
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.GridPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this),
                                'endDrag': Ext.bind(this.onPortletDrag, this),
                                'resize' :Ext.bind(this.onPortletResize, this)
                            }
                        }
```

I have made collapsed property to true. But because of this when I am trying to expand the portlet [after page load] I can see blank Grid.Plz. refer the attached image.

What is the problem ? do I need to do refresh or something ? because when I set collapsed to false I can see the grid.

Please suggest what is missing here.[image]

This is a code for the getTools: function(){

```
{
            type: 'Minimize',
            handler: function(e,target,panelHeader,tool){
                //panelHeader.ownerCt.toggleCollapse();
                if (panelHeader.ownerCt.collapsed)
                {
                    panelHeader.ownerCt.expand();

                }
                else {
                    panelHeader.ownerCt.collapse();
                }
            }
        }
```

for the first time when the portlet get load it is in collapsed state, Now when I click on cross icon not [the "^" for expand icons ] I can see the Blank grid.

Hope this time I am able to explain well.

Answer (score 0):

I took the Ext JS 4 example portal app and added your code (without the asterisks) to portlet-1. It is properly collapsed on load and expands to show the grid.

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you've posted. Perhaps you've changed the layout or layout properties of the surrounding container and that is affecting your portlet.

Here is my complete portal.js:

```js
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    //requires: [ 'Ext.diag.layout.ContextItem', 'Ext.diag.layout.Context' ],
    uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel', 'Ext.app.PortalColumn', 'Ext.app.GridPortlet', 'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'],

    getTools: function(){
        return [{
            xtype: 'tool',
            type: 'gear',
            handler: function(e, target, panelHeader, tool){
                var portlet = panelHeader.ownerCt;
                portlet.setLoading('Loading...');
                Ext.defer(function() {
                    portlet.setLoading(false);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }];
    },

    initComponent: function(){
        var content = '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.example.shortBogusMarkup+'</div>';

        Ext.apply(this, {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5' // pad the layout from the window edges
            },
            items: [{
                id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'box',
                region: 'north',
                height: 40,
                html: 'Ext Portal'
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    id: 'app-options',
                    title: 'Options',
                    region: 'west',
                    animCollapse: true,
                    width: 200,
                    minWidth: 150,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    split: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    layout:{
                        type: 'accordion',
                        animate: true
                    },
                    items: [{
                        html: content,
                        title:'Navigation',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        border: false,
                        iconCls: 'nav'
                    },{
                        title:'Settings',
                        html: content,
                        border: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        iconCls: 'settings'
                    }]
                },{
                    id: 'app-portal',
                    xtype: 'portalpanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'col-1',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-1',
                            title: 'Grid Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            collapsed: true,
                            height: 200,
                            autoscroll: true,
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.GridPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        },{
                            id: 'portlet-2',
                            title: 'Portlet 2',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-2',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-3',
                            title: 'Portlet 3',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.example.bogusMarkup+'</div>',
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-3',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-4',
                            title: 'Stock Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.ChartPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
        this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
    },

    showMsg: function(msg) {
        var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
            msgId = Ext.id();

        this.msgId = msgId;
        el.update(msg).show();

        Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
    },

    clearMsg: function(msgId) {
        if (msgId === this.msgId) {
            Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Portlet is getting collapsed there is no problem, but when I am trying to expand the by clicking on the icon I am getting blank Grid. So here is the problem. Instade of blank grid I should be able to get proper Grid. Please suggest what is missing here?

Comment: also for expand collapse here is the code ...if (panelHeader.ownerCt.collapsed)
             {
              panelHeader.ownerCt.expand();
             
             }
             else {
              panelHeader.ownerCt.collapse();
             }

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity. By "properly", I mean that it expands to show the grid for me.  I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: I am not sure How come it is working for you. I have attached my js file to my question, please suggest what is missing there.

Comment: I am not sure How come it is working for you. Few things i want to share, I have added one tool i.e. getTools: function() for  type: 'Minimize', and when I click on the cross icon from the image that I share [one Cross icon for close and another for minimize ] I am not able to see the Grid

Comment: @Atul Are you saying that your custom tool isn't collapsing correctly? If so, that is entirely different from your original post. Panel has built-in collapse and that is what I verified for you. Your custom tool will not be affected by the "collapse" config option.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, My apology , If I am not able to explain well. 
See let me explain again, 
I am using the getTool I have add "type: 'Minimize'" given above, 
Now when the page get load [First time] due to collapsed :true, by default portlet panel gets collapsed. Now I want to expand the collpased portlet, using the getTool's Minimize function, here the Portlet gets exapand, but Grid does not get expand I mean I can see the Grid as shown in the image that I post.

Comment: To replicate this, I have give my code as well as collpased config, Please suggest if still I am not able to explain properly. Also Suggest how can I send the whole code here, so that you will be able to correct me properly. Thanks for your efforts for me.

Comment: Rewrite your question to be about writing a custom collapse tool instead of what you have. You will probably get more help.